# Ajax query not working from server in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have developed an asp.net mvc3 application. There will be an initial view which searches for a list of customer and loads another view. I am doing this through ajax $.get function. It was working fine in my local machine. However, the same is not working in the server instance. There are no error messages also.

Code:

SearchCust.cshtml:

```
@model fbpm.Models.UserDetail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer List";
}

<h2>Search for a Customer</h2>

 Customer ID : <input type="text" id="cust" name="cust"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="button" onclick="handlesearch();"> Search </button>
<br />
<br />
<div id='custlist'> Enter the Customer ID in the above field and click Search </div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $.get('@Url.Action("Index", "User")?id=' + document.getElementById("cust").value,
        function (viewResult) {
            $("#custlist").html(viewResult);
        }); 
    function handlesearch() {
        $.get('@Url.Action("Index", "User")?id=' + document.getElementById("cust").value,
        function (viewResult) {
            $("#custlist").html(viewResult);
        });

    }
</script>
```

CODE: index.cshtml:

```
 @model IEnumerable<fbpm.Models.UserDetail>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>List of Customers</h2>
<button type="button" name="CreateUser" onclick="createuser();"> Create Customer </button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            User ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Password
        </th>
        <th>
            Customer Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Email ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Contact #1
        </th>
        <th>
            Contact #2
        </th>
        <th>
            Complete Address
        </th>
        <th>
            State
        </th>
        <th>
            Country
        </th>
        <th>
            Role
        </th>
        <th>
            PAN Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Project Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Booked Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Booked Amount
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    if (@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role).ToString().Equals("400"))
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PANNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookedDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookedAmount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID) }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID) }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID) })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
}

</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function createuser() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Create")';
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Now, the action class for this is:

```
public ViewResult SearchCust() {
    return View();
}

public ViewResult Index(string id)
{
   var cust = db.UserDetails.Where(c => c.UserID.Contains(id)); 
   return View(cust.ToList());
}
```

My browser gives the error:  It gives an error "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".. Not sure what I should be doing here. I have the jquery 1.9.1 min and even 1.8 also in the script files.

Please can someone help me on why this call is not coming up?

Regards,
Hari

Comment: Maybe should write your ajax code in `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: You need to be a more descriptive when you say it's not working. Does the page come up? What does the network tab in the browser's debug console show?

Comment: The page doesnt come up at all and there is no dump. And I havent coded anything for console write.

Comment: Your browser console will tell you something if there was a problem with the request.

Comment: Hi, Yes.. It gives an error "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".. Not sure what I should be doing here. I have the jquery 1.9.1 min and even 1.8 also in the script files..

Answer (score 0):

Due to your comment, make sure the jQuery library is the first script you load, right after your mark-up. Confirm through your browser that it is actually loaded as well.

```
<body>
    <!--your mark-up-->
    <!--jQuery script: either local file or from CDN (jQuery before jQuery UI)-->
    <!--rest of your scripts, putting the scripts that-->
    <!--are depended on in other scripts first-->
</body>
```

Comment: Do you say, it should be even before
@model fbpm.Models.UserDetail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer List";
}

Comment: Check your browser tools and make sure the library is loaded. Should be in the Console panel of Chrome or FF.

Comment: I shall give it a try. shall i include this library?
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bainternet-js-cdn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jQuery%20BlockUI%20Plugin/2.39/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

Comment: If your'e not worried about IE8 and before, I would just include the latest from the google CDN for jQuery and jQuery UI. If you need IE8 and earlier, go with 1.9.* for jQuery as jQuery cut off support @ 2.0. I edited my answer: jQuery has to come before jQuery UI for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

*It finally works!! :) All I had to do is just mcall the jquery src files and also add the user account to the Database!

Thank you all. *